# Is my calculation of the partial derivative of the cost function with respect to a single weight in the first layer correct?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, backpropagation, calculus

I'm trying to understand the chain rule of backpropagation.
This is what I understood. Is it correct?

[image]

$$ \frac{\partial E }{ \partial w} = \sum_{i} \frac{\partial E }{ \partial a_i^{(l)} } (\sum_{j} \frac{\partial a_i^{(l)} }{ \partial a_j^{(l-1)}  }(\sum_{k} \frac{\partial a_j^{(l-1)} }{ \partial a_k^{(l-2)}} \frac{\partial a_k^{(l-2)} }{ \partial z_k^{(l-2)}}  \frac{\partial z_k^{(l-2)} }{ \partial w}))$$

- $ a_i^{(l)}$ is the activation of the neuron $i$ in the $l$th layer
- $ z_i^{(l)} $ is the sum of multiplication of weights and previous activations
- $E$ is the error
- $w$ is the weight

Comment: Could you please clarify: Is the variable $\omega$ a single weight connecting one input to one neuron in the hidden layer (layer $l-2$)?

Comment: yes, it's the weight connecting the first input layer to the first neurone in the layer layer l−2